# React-Select not updating on change first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-jsonschema-forms

I've been trying to use `react-select` component inside my `react-json-schema-form` and the select field does not update on the first time.
this is the behaviour I am getting.
[Behaviour video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXqfp.gif)

The code:

```
    const CustomSelect = function (props) {
        return (
          <Select
            id="input"
            className="basic-single"
            classNamePrefix="select"
            options={props.options.enumOptions}
            placeholder={props.label}
            isSearchable={true}
            onChange={(e) => {
              props.onChange(e.value);
              if(props.schema.title === "WiFi model"){
                console.log(e.value)
              }
            }}
          ></Select>
        );

  };
```

The props are coming from RJSF, the enumOptions look like:

```
[{label: "3Com", value: "3Com"}
 {label: "4G Systems", value: "4G Systems"}
 {label: "7Links", value: "7Links"}
 {label: "8devices", value: "8devices"}
 {label: "ADB", value: "ADB"}
 {label: "ADI Engineering", value: "ADI Engineering"}
 {label: "ADSLR", value: "ADSLR"}
 {label: "ALFA Network", value: "ALFA Network"}]
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

The Parent RJSF:

```
<Form
        schema={schema}
        widgets={widgets}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        formData={formData}
      />
```

That's the parent component, I am using react-select as a custom component!

```
  const widgets = {
    SelectWidget: CustomSelect,
  };
```

For reference:
https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-customization/custom-widgets-fields/

Comment: Why `onChange` is async, any particular reason? can you share the parent component's code that is updating the state.

Comment: Yeah I was just experimenting to make it work, no particular reason,

Comment: First of all, your select component is missing `value` props. and please share the parent component's code too.

Comment: I've edited the question, with the parent component code, does that clear up things a bit?